# H1, Ul and H2 inline positioning with CSS

Tags: css, positioning, inline

I need to make responsive header with H1, UL menu and H2. 
The H1 - about 5% from the left corner. The H2 - about 5% from right corner. And between them is UL menu, which I need to place in the center. Everything in one line... And HR line under this line. 
How to position UL menu in the CENTER ?

[jsFiddle EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/rHhMt/)

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <header class="clearfix">
            <!-- TITLE 1 -->
            <h1>Title 1 </h1>
            <!-- UL -->
            <ul>
                <li> menu 1</li>
                <li> menu 2</li>
                <li> menu 3</li>
            </ul>
            <!-- TITLE 2 -->
            <h2>Title 2 <br/><span>span</span></h2>

        <hr />
    </header>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.container > header {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 40px 30px 20px 30px;
}
.container > header h1 {
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 37px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000;
    display:inline !important;
    float: left;
}
.container > header h2 {
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px auto;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000;
    display:inline !important;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
.container > header h2 span {
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000;
}
.container > header ul {
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: red;
}
.container > header ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}
.container > header hr {
    border:0;
    color:#000;
    background:#000;
    height:1px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Sorry... what's the question?

Comment: I don't know how to position UL menu in the responsive center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use floated `div`s and `text-align` to achieve this. Here's the HTML:

```
<header>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="center">Center</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</header>
```

And the CSS to align them properly:

```
.left { float: left; width: 25% }
.center { float: left; width: 50%; text-align: center; }
.right { float: left; width: 25%; text-align: right; }
```

[Here's a jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/SFAzg/)